# Javascript syntax error when trying to rewrite css in class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I try to hide component in react-js project by selecting the component class and changeing it to display none but this syntax error appeared

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; (12:25)
        if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
> 12 |         handleChange(event){
     |                          ^
  13 | 
  14 |         var x = document.getElementByClassName("kontaktformular");
  15 |         x.style.display = "none";
```

And also here is my code

```
if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
  handleChange(event) {
    var x = document.getElementByClassName("kontaktformular");
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
} else {
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: You need a semicolon after the function call, though it's really hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: It may be a bad code im not good at js, but my point is i want to hide the component with class kontaktformular on my landing page but i want it to be shown on all other pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
handleChange(event) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("kontaktformular")[0];
  if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

However, this is not the React way at all. The proper solution is to not render the contact form based on the current Route.
At the very least you'll want to use something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      { window.location.pathname !== "/" && <KontaktFormular /> }
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Note that it is getElement**s**ByClassName, which returns a collection.

Comment: neigther of them work, the react way i tried as the first option but its hide it from all of my pages.. and i cant figure out why

Comment: @SebastiánDanáč That means the condition is never true, so you need to figure out what the actual value of `...pathname` is. Did you try `console.log(window.location);` before returning the JSX?

Comment: Location {replace: ƒ, assign: ƒ, href: "http://localhost:3000/", ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "http://localhost:3000", …} - This is what the console sad

Comment: @SebastiánDanáč Right, but what about the `.pathname`? And if you are using `react-router`, surely there's a better way to find out which one the current page is?

Comment: It should be my landing page, the first page that opens when the server is started, http://localhost:3000/    so it must be the "/" ?, but yes iam using react-router

Comment: @SebastiánDanáč When the component in question gets rendered, what is the exact value of `pathname`, as per the console output? Surely it's different from `"/"` if you are on some other page? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: But the thing is if i set it to "/Kontakt" which i have defined as  <Route exact path='/Kontakt' component={Kontakt} /> in the router and shown link as http://localhost:3000/Kontakt its still hidden on all pages

Comment: And if i type window.location.pathname to the console it says "/"

Comment: @SebastiánDanáč If you want the form to appear on all pages, you cannot put it inside an exact route. Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2wj1658j6n

Comment: U know what i just discovered ? that when i load "/" the kontaktform is there but when i refresh it with cmd+R it dissapears, and when some subpage loads for instance /dashboard the kontaktform is not there but it should be there but when i refresh it with cmd+R the kontaktfro appear, thats some next level shit im in

Comment: And also when i build the project the kontaktform is not showing anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you should do this

```
var x = document.getElementByClassName("kontaktformular");
if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
    x.style.display = "none";

} else {
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Yes but why? There's no real need to declare another function there.

Comment: but you are declaring and defining a function so in vanilla js you need write function before declaring and defining it

Comment: Thanks man its fixed the syntax error but the code dont work as i espected, i want to hide the component with class kontaktformular on my landing page so in the "/" but on all the other pages i want it to be there

Comment: It may be a bad code im not good at js, but my point is i want to hide the component with class kontaktformular on my landing page but i want it to be shown on all other pages

Comment: > 26 | var x = document.getElementByClassName("kontaktformular"); This error appeard on it

Comment: All right its working but because of some reason its hiding the component from all sites not just the one it should